# Split vector polygon with a line - GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, vector, splitting

I was wondering if in GRASS GIS exists a way to split a polygonal area based on its intersection with a vector line, eg:

```
 ______                      ______
|      |                    |  *   |
|  *   |  + __________  ->  |______|
|      |                    |  *   |
|______|                    |______|

1 polygon  +  1 line    ->  2 polygons
```

Answer (score 2):

This workflow might help (assuming a polygon vector "polys" and a line vector "lines":

```
v.type input=polys out=boundary_lines from=boundary to=line
v.patch boundary_lines,lines out=lines_patch
v.type input=lines_patch out=new_boundary  # default is from lines to boundaries
v.centroids new_boundary out=new_areas
```

Note that you loose the polys attribute table. You'll have to do some `v.distance` trickery to attach original poly attributes to the new_areas.

Comment: Probably also v.edit would do the job? Similar to https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.edit.html#add-new-features-to-existing-vector-map

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way but for now what I do is:

- create a polygon from the line with "v.buffer"
- use v.overlay to extract a polygon layers composed by the union of the 2 polygon
- use again v.overlay to extract only the polygons that are not overlaid by the buffered line

this gives me 2 polygons with an empty space where the buffered line was ... it is not optimal ...