# GRASS 7 PYTHON and spatial sql request

Tags: python, grass-gis, sql

In a python script, I can't access the geometry of my tables :

```
SQL_req = 'SELECT id_parcel, id_melba FROM parcels, network WHERE st_intersects(parcels.geometry, network.geometry)'
grass.write_command("db.select", input='-', stdin=SQL_req, stdout = DEVNULL, stderr = DEVNULL)
```

gives :

```
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
SELECT id_parcel, id_melba FROM parcels, network WHERE st_intersects(parcels.geometry, network.geometry)
no such column: parcels.geometry
```

Shapefiles were imported with v.in.ogr and other sql requests are correctly ending. That's when I try to use spatial functions that it don't work.

Any suggest or example?

Answer (score 1):

In the GRASS vector model, there is no geometry stored in the SQL database. The backend SQL database is for attributes only. Geometry is stored in a special set of GRASS files.

You should be looking at the native GRASS modules for selection/intersection. etc such as `v.overlay` or `v.select`.

Comment: Or, use GRASS to export to shapefile, and load the shapefile directly in Python to work with the geometry.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by loading shapefile **directly**?

Comment: I'd like to use spatial functions. For example : st_split because I didn't find  a module in GRASS that splits polygons with a polyline.

Comment: Loading the shapefile directly into python means using `pyshp` or gdal python bindings, not GRASS.

Comment: Regarding spliting polygons in GRASS, Did you see the answer posted here: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237818/split-vector-polygon-with-a-line-grass-gis]